# How to transform an object1 into another object2 after "player" has a collision with object1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new in Unity and c#. I need you help.

How to transform an object1 into another object2 after "player" has a collision with object1?

We have "Player" and object1, object2 and object3.

So, things start with "Player" and "object1". When "Player" collides with "object1", "object1" should transform into "object2" (in the same place where "object1" was).

When "Player"  collides with "object2", "object2" should transform in "object3", in the same place as "object2" was.

When "Player"  collides with "object3", "object3" should transform in "object1", in the same place as "object3" was.

So it should switch in order, "object1" to "object2" to "object3" and then restart in "object1" again.
This should happen every time "Player" collides with the object.

Thanks.

using UnityEngine;

public class Switch : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject prefab2; // The prefab to change into

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // Check if the collision is with an object tagged as "Player"
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        newObject.transform.localScale = transform.localScale;

        // Destroy the old object (prefab1)
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: that code looks fine.  whats wrong with it?

Comment: @BugFinder I would assume some sort of endless loop replacement since the new spawned object might "immediately" also collide with the player and directly triggers its replacement with the next one ^^

Comment: true @derHugo except you could also argue that there maybe some delay code in form of some await/coroutine, as its not been shared.. who knows right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided only a tiny snippet of a large code it's hard to asses it but it probably comes down to 2 possible problems.

1. The code of the second and third prefab might not be adjusted adequately. Do they each create the next-in-line prefab? If you accidentally just copied and pasted the code then they would all at impact create the second prefab in their place. Also, the creation of the new object and destruction of the old one being in a script that's in the destroyed object could make it harder to add other elements to the game. I would suggest a GameManager script that would macro manage these things, only optional though.
2. When you create the new game object in the same place as the old, based on current information it's very likely the new object would collide with the player the moment it spawns, creating an infinite loop. Even if you have something to stop this on another script(maybe the player-collider script), this could still cause problems because the scripts might execute in an order that creates a loop. I would again suggest detecting impacts at a local level, but handling their consequences at a 'global' level. I'm fairly certain it would fix all of your problems.

Hope I helped,
Good Luck(;

Answer (score 0):

I would put a script on the player and check for a tag like "objects" and then increment through a List of prefabs and just loop this number, and to avoid instant collisions I would also move the next object a small amount away from the player after the collision, like this (Have not tested):

```
public GameObject[] prefabs;
int index = 0;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // Check if the collision is with one of the objects
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Object"))
    {
        //add the new object at the same spot but moved slightly away
        //in direction of collision
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefabs[index], (collosion.transform.position - transform.position) * 0.01f + collosion.transform.position, collision.transform.rotation);

        newObject.transform.localScale = collision.transform.localScale;

        // Destroy the old object (prefab1)
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        //increase but loop back to 0
        index = index++ % prefabs.Length;
    }
}
```